# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm learning `discord.js` and I'm trying to follow [this tutorial on discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#reading-command-files), but this error occurs:

```js
client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

`index.js` code on the errored part:

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 32767 });
client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.ts'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command); // errored part
}
```

If you need more code, please tell it to me.

Comment: At least one of your command files doesn't have a `data` property. Try adding `console.log("registering command", file, command.data?.name)` in your loop.

Comment: Hey everyone, this is an old post but I will bump it. I can still remember that I did @新Acesyyy 's answer but what I forgot during the time was that I completed a command. I did some Ctrl+z later and forgot that I undid 新Acesyyy 's answer. So sorry for causing some confusion, hopefully, you will sleep tonight.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

delete the `data` on your code line

```
client.commands.set(command.name, command); //this will set your command name
```

Edit: I didn't recognize the `.ts` but I'm sure it's the same properties with `.js`

Comment: Please limit bold headings.

Comment: This probably doesn't provide an answer to the question and should be a comment only. You don't really have any idea what `command` is so you should ask OP for clarification instead. Anyway, if OP follows the instructions they provided, `command.data.name` should be correct.

Comment: After looking to my `slash command handler` I've seen that I'm using `command.data.name` so sorry for miss information.

Comment: No worries, you can always edit or delete incorrect answers ;)

Comment: I got correct answer? Wait what

Comment: Hey everyone, this is an old post but I will bump it. I can still remember that I did @新Acesyyy 's answer but what I forgot during the time was that I completed a command. I did some Ctrl+z later and forgot that I undid 新Acesyyy 's answer. So sorry for causing some confusion, hopefully, you will sleep tonight.